# Passing same coworker quick succession greeting etiquette

Tags: colleagues

Say you walk pass a coworker and say hello, but then pass him again not 30 seconds later. Do you need to say hello again or is it ok to just keep walking? Assuming it's someone that is barely an acquaintance.

Comment: You must stop for a 10 minute chat and a cup of tea. :)

Comment: Better opt for a traditional dance-off

Comment: Don't forget the classic "are you stalking me!!??" - always hilarious.

Comment: Do the thing where you're trying to get past but you both go the same way and then tge other way and do that little dance.

Comment: Say "jinx" and then they can't speak for the rest of the day.

Answer (score 6):

Do the hallway nod: Subtle nod or smile to your co-worker to acknowledge their presence, but don't wait long for them to return it just continue minding your business.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you need to say hello again or is it ok to just keep walking?

It's fine to just keep walking. There's no obligation to say the first 'Hello' although it's polite to.